# Endless loop, can't find error

Tags: c++, string, comparison, infinite-loop

I'm making a small program for myself and any of my friends at school to use. I have a function (C++), called getChoice(), that returns a choice that the user made:

```
std::string getChoice(const std::string& s)
{
    std::string choice;
    if (s == "sp")
    {
        do
        {
            std::cout << "Do you want to search for a video or play it? (s/p): ";
            std::cin >> choice;

            if (choice[0] == 'S' || choice[0] == 'P')
                choice[0] = tolower(choice[0]);

        } while (choice.compare("s") != 0 || choice.compare("p") != 0);
    }
    else if (s == "vidtype")
    {
        do
        {
            std::cout << "Do you want to use vine or yt? (vine/yt): ";
            std::cin >> choice;

        } while (choice.compare("vine") != 0 || choice.compare("yt") != 0);
    }

    else
    {
        std::cout << "Uh, this function only supports \"sp\" and \"vidtype\"\n\n";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

return choice;
}
```

My issue is that the program gets stuck in an infinite loop at

```
"Do you want to search for a video or play it? (s/p): ";
```

I've rewritten the entire program, and that didn't fix it. I've looked up on using !=; it seems that I should use std::string.compare(). 
And I also tried outputting choice after using std::cin. It looks just fine in console output, showing s and p, but the tests in the do-while both fail somehow. Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: You get a downvote for not debugging the logic it yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
while (choice.compare("s") != 0 || choice.compare("p") != 0);
```

If not S or not P:

- If you input S, not P will evaluate to true, this continuing the loops
- If you input P, not S will evaluate to true, this continuing the loops
- If you input anything other than S or P, both will be true, this continuing the loop.

You probably meant to do:

```
while (choice.compare("s") != 0 && choice.compare("p") != 0);
```

If not S and not P (aka some other character besides S and P).

---

This incorrect logic is also present in your second loop (thank you [dwcanillas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1359034/dwcanillas))

```
while (choice.compare("vine") != 0 || choice.compare("yt") != 0);
```

Comment: Just thought I'd note that his other loop has the same problem as well.

Comment: Ah. Silly me. Thanks, all, that fixed it! And I did see that, for the second loop, but to keep it simple I just asked for the first loop. :)

Comment: @LordZsolt Yeah, I will, it's just not letting me since this was answered (or asked) in such a short time frame. Couple minutes left.

Answer (score 2):

Change the condition in the while loop the following way

```
    do
    {
        std::cout << "Do you want to search for a video or play it? (s/p): ";
        std::cin >> choice;

        if (choice[0] == 'S' || choice[0] == 'P')
            choice[0] = tolower(choice[0]);

    } while (choice.compare("s") != 0 && choice.compare("p") != 0);
```

It is easier to consider the negation of the condition when the loop has to be terminated. For example

```
!(choice.compare("s") != 0 && choice.compare("p") != 0)
```

or more visually

```
not (choice.compare("s") != 0 && choice.compare("p") != 0)
```

is equivalent to

```
choice.compare("s") == 0 || choice.compare("p") == 0
```

So when the user entered either "s" or "p" then exit the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the line

```
while (choice.compare("s") != 0 || choice.compare("p") != 0);
```

If you change the logic to

```
while (choice.compare("s") == 0 || choice.compare("p") == 0);
```

it will be good.